# Using before/after insert on SQL server in Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am connecing to my SQL server instance via ODBC database feature in Access 2010. I can make form to add new records for my table. But many options are unavaiable. Like making "After insert" makro, providing Queries. Can i do something to allow such things, or it is impossible while connecting to SQL database.

Comment: Since you are connecting to sql server, have you considered creating a trigger to take the place of your "after insert" macro?

Comment: the problemis i need to do web form for sharepoint use. And i cannot do it using SQL server database. Or am i wrong?